# Get class which isn't in any namespace

Tags: .net-4.0

How can I get access to a class which isn't in any namespace ? I'm writing building scripts.

Comment: What are you currently trying, and what is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You simply refer to it by class name. Eg:

```
public class Foo
{
}
```

You simply refer to it as `Foo`.